# Inject two specific interface implementations into constructor with Simple Injector

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I have and interface `IConnector`. And have some implementations, say `SomeConnector`. And my use case looks like:

```
public class Worker : IWorker
{
    public Worker(IConnector dataConnector, IConnector transactionConnector) {}
}

public class SomeConnector : IConnector
{
    public SomeConnector(IConnectorContext connectorContext) {}
}
```

In the `Worker` constructor I need to have two instances of `IConnector`. And not just two instances, but two specific instances, created with their own contexts. How can I make this registration?

**Update1**

Adding `ConnectorContext` implementation

```
public class SomeConnectorContext : IConnectorContext
{
    public List<string> Types { get; }
    public int DataTimeoutSeconds { get; }
    public string Key { get; }
    public string ConnectorName { get; }

    public SomeConnectorContext(
        List<string> types, int dataTimeoutSeconds, string key, string connectorName)
    {
        Types = types;
        DataTimeoutSeconds = dataTimeoutSeconds;
        Key = key;
        ConnectorName = connectorName;
    }
}
```

**Update2**

In fact I need some kind of conditional registration based on config. For example something like:

```
switch (workerType)
{
    // the following code is obviously incorrect, because I
    // don't know how make registrations properly in this case.
    case "worker1":
        //create context for dataConnector based on config.
        Container.Register<IConnectorContext>(new SomeConnectorContext(...));
        //this is dataConnector. and should use dataConnector context.
        Container.Register<IConnector, SomeConnector>();

        //create context for transactionConnector based on config.
        Container.Register<IConnectorContext>(new SomeConnectorContext(...));
        //this is transactionConnector. and should use transactionConnector context.
        Container.Register<IConnector, SomeConnector>();

        Container.Register<IWorker, Worker1>();
        break;

    //in the following case Worker2 needs only one Connector
    case "worker2":
        //create context for allPurposeConnector based on config.
        Container.Register<IConnectorContext>(new SomeConnectorContext(...));
        //this is allPurposeConnector. and should use allPurposeConnector context.
        Container.Register<IConnector, SomeConnector>();

        Container.Register<IWorker, Worker2>();
        break;
}
```

**Update3**
Adding workerType assignment example.

workerType is a configuration value. For example it can be set like this:
`workerType = Properties.Settings.Default.WorkerType;`

Comment: Can you elaborate under which conditions do you choose between `Worker1` and `Worker2`. Is the `workerType` a configuration value, or is it passed along with the request? Can you show a code example that demonstrates this?

Comment: Introducing those "hard" dependencies via IOC might be a bit dirty. Maybe a cleaner solution would be to introduce a "ConnectorFactory", inject this and let its consumer decide what they need?

Comment: I'm afraid that this factory is going to be a bit cumbersome. Especially if number of worker types and number of connectors will grow. And to make thing worse different connectors may need different number of connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see 2 options.

You can hand-wire your dependencies by using a lambda. This means you only register `IWorker` and build it and its dependencies manually. This disables Auto-Wiring, but results in quite straightforward code, as shown in this example:

```
switch (workerType)
{
    case "worker1":
        var context1 = new SomeConnectorContext(...);
        var context2 = new SomeConnectorContext(...);

        Container.Register<IWorker>(() => Worker1(
            new SomeConnector(context1),
            new SomeConnector(context2)));
        break;

    case "worker2":
        var context1 = new SomeConnectorContext(...);

        Container.Register<IWorker>(() => Worker1(
            new SomeConnector(context1)));
        break;
}
```

You second option is to register `SomeConnector` as conditional registration. This allows you to make both `SomeConnector` registrations, and link them to their corresponding constructor parameters. This allows `IWorker` to be Auto-Wired, but does result in a more complex registration, as shown below:

```
switch (workerType)
{
    case "worker1":
        var context1 = new SomeConnectorContext(...);
        Container.RegisterConditional<SomeConnector>(
            Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(
            () => new SomeConnector(context1), container),
            c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "dataConnector");

        var context2 = new SomeConnectorContext(...);
        Container.RegisterConditional<SomeConnector>(
            Lifestyle.Transient.CreateRegistration(
            () => new SomeConnector(context2), container),
            c => c.Consumer.Target.Name == "transactionConnector");

        Container.Register<IWorker, Worker1>();
        break;

    case "worker2":
        Container.Register<IConnectorContext>(new SomeConnectorContext(...));
        Container.Register<IConnector, SomeConnector>();
        Container.Register<IWorker, Worker2>();
        break;
}
```